# event.target is not working properly in ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery

> > This is not working in ie8 . How i fix it?

```
var $target = $(e.target)
var $rows = $target.closest('tr').next();
$rows.hide();
```

$(".e-gridcontent").find(".e-recordplusexpand").closest("tr").next().hide() - not working in ie8

Comment: show us the full code??

Comment: show us the html and the complete event handler... also is there any error

Comment: @JqueryKing, Not _me_ us

Comment: $(".e-gridcontent").find(".e-recordplusexpand").closest("tr").next().hide()                                      not working in ie8  how fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this:

```
window.event || e
```

for example:

```
$("#id")[0].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var evt = window.event || e; // for old browser
    console.log(evt.target)
});
```

Or just in jquery:

```
$("#id").click(function(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
});
```

Because jQuery handle ie8 event.